# Error while installing livewire 3 through composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I have some problems with installing livewire 3 package, I am getting this:

> Problem 1
> Root composer.json requires livewire/livewire 3.0@beta, found livewire/livewire[dev-throw-error-when-testing-non-livewire-class, ..., dev-bad-hotfix-test, v0.0.1, ..., v0.7.4, v1.0.0, ..., 1.x-dev, v2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev, v3.0.0-beta.1, v3.0.0-beta.2, v3.0.0-beta.3] but it does not match the constraint.
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content

installing livewire 3 like website document.

Comment: You did not add the most important part, what command did you run? If you run `composer require livewire/livewire@^3` it does not exist, it is `3.0.0-beta`, the latest version is `2.12.3`. You can check the version on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/livewire/livewire)

Comment: Thats right, I run "composer need livewire/livewire:^3.0@beta" before, but now it works with "composer need livewire/livewire:3.0.0-beta.3".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be able to install the beta of Livewire v3 with the following command,

```
composer require livewire/livewire "^3.0.*@beta"
```

Since Livewire v3 still is in beta, you need to append the `@beta` flag.

Comment: The command is not working for me. It throws `Could not parse version constraint ^3.0.*: Invalid version string "^3.0.*"` error. Also the command in the docs doesn't work either.

Using `composer require livewire/livewire:v3.0.0-beta.4` for now

Answer (score 3):

The docs at [livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart) suggest you use:

```
composer require livewire/livewire:^3.0@beta
```

If that fails, try to add quotes around the version number and beta flag

```
composer require livewire/livewire "^3.0@beta"
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried following the docs which suggests to write:

```
composer require livewire/livewire "^3.0@beta"
```

Then I followed @Qirel's reply which is:

```
composer require livewire/livewire "^3.0.*@beta"
```

and I managed to install Livewire V3 in my Laravel project.

Comment: This worked for me, using Laravel 10